# Can oozie control jobs outside of Hadoop?

Tags: oozie

From documentation, it isn't very clear whether oozie can schedule and control jobs outside of Hadoop? Can someone shed some light on this? If not, is there any open source based workflow engine which can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try consider using chronos (from airbnb) advanced version of cron with a UI, built on top of mesos. airbnb.github.com/chronos/

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe no. Because Oozie itself does not have a resource management policy, all it does is submitting jobs to Hadoop's job tracker at the right time. Besides, for each Oozie workflow, there will be one launcher job which is responsible for submitting the real jobs in the workflow to Hadoop. The launcher job is itself a Hadoop job. So, I think for the versions earlier than Oozie 3.2, the answer should be no.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider trying [azkaban by linked in](http://data.linkedin.com/opensource/azkaban/quick-start). It was specifically built for hadoop. But unix commands can be specified in the job file of azkaban. So you may develop a workflow for any application(s) that can be run using command line.

Answer (score -1):

I've been working on a new workflow engine called Soop. https://github.com/radixCSgeek/soop it is very lightweight and simple to setup and run using a cron-like syntax. It can run any Java POJO as well as running shell processes, so you can kick off a bash script or whatever.